# How to highlight the area tag of the image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the chart image in the below link. which has the series and points and i have created area tag for each points. Now i want to highlight the points on mouse hover.

Image link: http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/Chart/Chart-CPAAAW/

```
$($('series0').children('area').last()).maphilight();
```

I used this code. but no useful.

Anyone help on this.

Thanks,
Bharathiraja.

Comment: The image link you included is broken

Comment: I have modified link.. please check it

Comment: You need to clarify your question as well.  I can't tell what you are asking

Comment: I want to highlight the point when mouse over on the specific point